# how to handle Error connect ECONNREFUSED in Postman, in MERN project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, error-handling, postman, mern

I an developing a MERN stack website, while trying to link MongoDB database to my app using Postman. It is showing 500 internal server error. I have gone through whole code and syntax of my code but cannot figureout how to resolve this issue.
[This is what terminal is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RULA.png)

I tried to add current ip address to whitelist but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you're confusing Postman and API which are 2 separate things.